# Add tinymce to new textarea dynamically

Tags: jquery, tinymce, html-editor

How can i do this

```
function addTinyText(id, text){
//add textarea to DOM
$('<textarea id="txt'+id+'"></textarea>').append(text).appendTo('body');
//init tineMCE
 tinyMCE.init({
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "emotions,spellchecker"
});
//add tinymce to this
tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", false, 'txt'+id);
}
```

but as a result every time we have a new textarea+tinyMCE but no text inside

What do i wrong?

Comment: this works well on my system (FF9), which browser are you using?

Comment: my browser is Chrome 16 -- and my code really works well on it. mb any conflicts wuz there

Comment: problem, if text contains tags as <p></p><img /> and others

Comment: can you show me what the variable text holds? (i think i might now what's wrong here)

Comment: mb solution is tinyMCE.get('textareaId').setContent('<p>html</p>')  after tinymce load. Is there onload trigger?

Comment: you may also use your code inside a document.ready block

Comment: I try to set this function as a callback of a button
and I wish that the area was created when I clicked on the button

if I make button 1 (create textarea with mce) and button 2 (set content to textarea). after that i'll click on 1st button, wait for tinymce is loaded, than click on the 2nd button -- everything will be ok

Comment: ok, so where do you still encounter problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

line

```
$('<textarea id="txt'+id+'"></textarea>').append(text).appendTo('body');
```

should be line

```
$('<textarea id="txt'+id+'"></textarea>').text(text).appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 3):

I searched a very long time to find an answer to a similar problem.

My content was not being posted even thou I could get the editor to appear.

I got it working like this:

```
    jQuery('.wysiwyg').tinymce({
      // Location of TinyMCE script
      script_url : 'path/tinymce/tiny_mce.js',

      // General options
      theme : "advanced",
     .........
     .........
     ......... etc
```

I used the standard jquery code to initiate all text areas with class name wysiwyg as tinymce objects.

After ajax call completes and new textarea is loaded I run this function:

```
jQuery(".wysiwyg").each(function(){ 
    tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl",false, this.id);
});
```

Now my code is finally being posted correctly.

Comment: @DentraAndres Thank you very much. This is a big fail on all tutorials and blog posts on this subject. Important detail if you are trying to dynamically initialize a TinyMCE textarea..

Comment: For other people who read this: I was running TinyMCE 4.0.28, which required me to change `mceAddControl` to `mceAddEditor`.  This is true for the current version of TinyMCE (5.2.0-75) as well, as of Mar 16, 2020