# To append a text area in form with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to append a text area in to the form. But the form is also appended first time. Lets look to my code.

```
  jQuery('.addeducation-sym').click( function(){
    var tiny_mce = '<textarea name="content"></textarea>';
    jQuery('.extra-form').clone().appendTo('#edu-form');
    tiny_mce.appendTo('#edu-form .extra-form');
  });
```

In the above code when i click the '.addeducation-sym' botton i got the form name '.extra-form'. This was a clone of a html form like bellow.

```
        <div  class="extra-form">
            <label for="education-info">Extra Educational Information</label>
            <input type="text" name="coursename" id="firstname" value="coursename" />
            <input type="text" name="institutename" id="institutename" value="institutename" />
            <input type="text" name="startdate" id="startdate" value="startdate" />
            <input type="text" name="enddate" id="enddate" value="enddate" />
        </div>      <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->
```

After that i want to append another html code which is stored in a variable called 'tiny_mce'. But i could not find any update in my code. So please let me know what is the way to append a '' to the "extra-form" after it is cloned.

Comment: This is probably an issue with delegation. Take a look at the `on` method to delegate events for future instances. Also try `clone( true )` to keep the events associated with the cloned element.

Comment: You should init `var tiny_mce = '<textarea name="content"></textarea>';` as a jQuery object lik `var tiny_mce = jQuery('<textarea name="content"></textarea>');`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do:

```
jQuery(document).on("click", '.addeducation-sym', function(){
    jQuery('.extra-form').clone(true).appendTo('#edu-form');
    $("<textarea />", {
        "name" : "content"
    }).appendTo('#edu-form .extra-form');
});
```

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6BdQE/)

Comment: Thank you, but i use the text area as a tinyMCE editor. can you say me why the text area not convert to tinyMCE editor.

Comment: @Rain for converting textarea to tinyMCE editor you need to use tinyMCE plugin which i dont see in your code. See more on it here:: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:editor_selector

Comment: Yes, i use this for the previous form. Okay i have said the details what i wnat, ihave a form in which i used tinyMCE plugin. That is working fine. When i append the text area in the extra form i want to add a tinyMCE editor to the the appended form. Can it possible ?

Comment: @Rain you mean something like in here:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091619/add-tinymce-to-new-textarea-dynamically