# How to apply the tinymce editor by jquery append method

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I have one Button `#add_text` and DIV `#appreciation`...
If I put the textarea for the TinyMCE editor directly to the html code it works

But I want to append dynamically Tinymce by clicking the button...

How to append the **Tinymce Editor** using **jQuery's append Method**?

```
$("#add_text").click(function(){
 $("#appreciation").append("<textarea id='test' class='adtext'></textarea>");
});
```

The above code is not working as expected...

How can I achieve that the TinyMCE is working for the dynamically added textarea

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle ?

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: which version of tinymce you are using?

Answer (score 1):

You need to init the TinyMCE to add the functionality to the new textarea after appending the textarea to the div:

[Add tinymce to new textarea dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091619/add-tinymce-to-new-textarea-dynamically)

http://blog.mirthlab.com/2008/11/13/dynamically-adding-and-removing-tinymce-instances-to-a-page/

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#temp_Name").click(function () {

        $("#temp_Description").empty();
        $("#temp_Context").empty();
         $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("insertcontext")', // we are calling json method
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
             data: { contex: $("#hidden1").val() },

             success: function (edtx) {

                 $("#temp_Description").html("");
                 $("#temp_Context").html("");// clear before appending new list

                 $.each(edtx, function (i, city1) {
                     $("#temp_Description").val(city1.temp_Description);

                     var dataa = city1.temp_Context;

                     $("#temp_Context").data(city1.temp_Context);
                     tinymce.get("temp_Context").setContent(dataa);

                         //$('<option></option>').val(city1.temp_Description).html(city1.temp_Description));
                });
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
            }
        });
        return false;
    })
```

Comment: tinymce.get("temp_Context").setContent(dataa); for append data