# Trying to load appending textareas with tinymce

Tags: php, jquery, forms, laravel, tinymce

I am working with a form which has one default textarea field and I am using TinyMCE with that field which working without any problem - other than that I have few optional textarea fields which user can add by clicking a button - that button when clicked append the form with same type of textarea field but the problem is, the newly added optional textarea field doesn't load with TinyMCE but the simple HTML textarea field

This is what I am doing

The default textarea field in HTML form

```
<div class="form-group"> 
    <label for="service_overview">Service Overview *</label> 
    <div class="input-group"> 
        <div class="input-group-addon"> 
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> 
        </div> 
        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="service_overview[]" aria-required="true" required="s" placeholder="Service Overview" class="form-control">
        </textarea> 
        <span class="input-group-addon danger"> 
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> 
        </span> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

The jQuery code to append another textarea field in form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".services"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_service_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            initMCEall();
            $(wrapper).append('<div><div class="clearfix">{{ Form::button("Remove service", ["class" => "btn btn-danger remove_field"]) }}</div><div class="form-group"> {{ Form::label("service_title", "Service Title *") }} <div class="input-group"> <div class="input-group-addon"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> </div> {{ Form::text("service_title[]", null, ["class" => "form-control", "placeholder" => "Service Title", "required" => "s", "id" => "itName", "aria-required" => "true"]) }} <span class="input-group-addon danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> </span> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> {{ Form::label("service_overview", "Service Overview *") }} <div class="input-group"> <div class="input-group-addon"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> </div> {{ Form::textarea("service_overview[]", null, ["class" => "form-control", "placeholder" => "Service Overview", "required" => "s", "aria-required" => "true"]) }} <span class="input-group-addon danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> </span> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput"> <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"> <img data-src="holder.js/100%x100%" alt="..."></div> <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px;"></div> {{ Form::file("service_image[]") }} </div> </div></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
</script>
```

The code to initiate TinyMCE with textareas

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initMCEall(){
  tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas"
  });
}
// add all textarea elements to document
initMCEall();
</script>
```

What I want is that when a user load another Textarea the TinyMCE editor should be integrated with the added textarea too just like the default textarea

Comment: Maybe duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091619/add-tinymce-to-new-textarea-dynamically