# how to add a tinymce editor to a dynamically added textarea?

Tags: jquery, tinymce

Guys recently i finished a infinite scroll to one of my projects using jquery, php and mysql. After creating that i face the problem of tinymce editor not binding to the dynamically generated textarea. What should i do?
here is the code for tinymce editor:

```
tinymce.init({
    menubar:false,
    forced_root_block : "",
    selector: "textarea#wall_edit_1",
     entities : '160,nbsp,162,cent,8364,euro,163,pound',
    theme: "modern",
    resize: false,
    height: 200,
    plugins: [
         " autolink link image preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
         "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
         "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons paste textcolor"
   ],
   content_css: "css/content.css",
   toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | l      ink image | print preview media fullpage |  emoticons", 
   style_formats: [
        {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
      //  {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
        {title: 'Header', block: 'h1'},
        {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
        {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
        {title: 'Table styles'},
        {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
    ]
    });
```

here is the php code that dynamically generates the textarea while using the infinite scroll feature in jquery:

```
if ($author==$_SESSION['uname'] || $account_name==$_SESSION['uname']) {
                $statusdeletebutton='<li>'
                           . '<a  type="'.$updateid.'" class="btn delete_4_session hidden_text_delete_'.$updateid.' glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete_status_btn" title="Delete this status and its replies">Remove</a></li>';
                $edit_btn='<li>'
                        . '<a attr="'.$updateid.'" type="'.$updateid.'" class="btn edit_4_session hidden_text_edit glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Edit this status" >Edit</a></li>';
                $statusui_edit="<div type='".$updateid."' class='hidden_edit_4_session session_editor".$updateid." jumbotron'>"
            . "<a type='".$updateid."' class='btn pull-right close_edit' title='Close without editing'>Close X</a>"
            . "<input type='text' class='form-control title_s_edit title_s_".$updateid."' name='status_title' value='".html_entity_decode($title)."' placeholder='Title' >"
            . "<span>&nbsp;</span>"
            . "<textarea id='wall_edit_1' type='".$updateid."' rows='5' cols='50'  class='session_edit text_value_".$updateid."' wrap='hard' placeholder='whats up ".$session_uname."'>
             ".html_entity_decode($data1)."</textarea><br>"
            . "<button style='float:right;' value='".$updateid."' type='a' class='btn btn-warning btn btn-large btn-lg post-s-edit'>Update</button></div>" ;

                }else{
                    $statusdeletebutton="";
                    $edit_btn="<li class='posted'>You are not the owner of this Post</li>";
                    $statusui_edit="";
                }

       echo $statusui_edit.''. $hidden_text.'<div attr="'.$updateid.'" type="'.$updateid.'" class="statusboxes status_'.$updateid.'  jumbotron">'
                        . '<h3 class="pull-left title">'
                        . '<div id="'.$updateid.'" class="title_s_2copy posted" value="'.html_entity_decode($title).'">'.html_entity_decode($title).'</div></h3>'
                        . '<span class="pull-right">'
                        . '<div class="dropdown">'
                        . '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  >'
                        . '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>'
                        . '<ul class="dropdown-menu">'
                         .$edit_btn .' '. $statusdeletebutton .'</ul></div></span><br><hr>'
                        . '<legend><span style="font-size: 13.5px;" class=" data_s_2copy" type="'.$updateid.'" >'
                        . html_entity_decode($data1).'</span></legend><b class="posted"><small>Posted by:-  <a href="home.php?u='.$author.'"><img src="'.$feed_pic.'" height="20px" width="20px"> '.$author.   '</a>   '.$datemade.'</small></b>'
                        . '<br><legend>'.$like.' | '.$unlike. ' | '.$share_button.'<h4><a id="'.$updateid.'" class="btn collap-btn">Comments</a></h4></legend>';
```

here is the place where i init it in jquery @rob:

```
    $(document).on("click",".hidden_text_edit",function(){
    var id=$(this).attr("type");

    $(".session_editor"+id).removeClass("hide");
    $(".session_editor"+id).show(function(){
        tinymce.init({
    menubar:false,
    forced_root_block : "",
    selector: "textarea#wall_edit_1",
     entities : '160,nbsp,162,cent,8364,euro,163,pound',
    theme: "modern",
    resize: false,
    height: 200,
    plugins: [
         " autolink link image preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
         "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
         "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons paste textcolor"
   ],
   content_css: "css/content.css",
   toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | l      ink image | print preview media fullpage |  emoticons", 
   style_formats: [
        {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
      //  {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
        {title: 'Header', block: 'h1'},
        {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
        {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
        {title: 'Table styles'},
        {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
    ]
    });
    });

    $(".status_"+id).hide();

    });
```

Comment: check this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091619/add-tinymce-to-new-textarea-dynamically

Comment: @RanjeetSingh that is of no help to me :(

Comment: Where is your `init()` call for the new `<textarea>`?  When you add a `textarea` after the initial call to `init()` you need to call `init()` after the `<textarea>` is added to the page.  The `init()` function does not add TinyMCE to selectors added after the `init()` call is complete.

Comment: @MichaelFromin i have included it as asked.

Comment: So are you using the same ID for each `<textarea>`?  If so that is your issue - regardless of whether or not its visible on the page you can only have one DOM element with a given ID.

Comment: i tried changing the Id to a dynamic one too still no use @MichaelFromin

Comment: @shan2batman Can you provide a demo page where this is running?  Without seeing this code in action its hard to provide more guidance.

Comment: @MichaelFromin currently i have it in my local machine, i'll create a small screencast and mail it to you for help. if that is ok you can pm me your mail.

Comment: @shan2batman At this point people need to see running code to help debug this further ... such as the resultant HTML that is placed in the page based on the PHP and what (if any) JavaScript errors exist.  A video won't help much.

Comment: @MichaelFromin ok i'll find a way to address the problem and contact you as soon as possible.

Comment: @MichaelFromin here is the link to that app http://express-pad4u.rhcloud.com/ .use the username:qwerty and pass:123456

Comment: @MichaelFromin notice that the problem occurs only after the infinite scroll function work.

Comment: @MichaelFromin do you have any idea on how to solve this problem bro!

Comment: @GauravSrivastava how can i make this work bro?

Comment: That login does not work for me ... and if it did you have not defined the exact steps I need to take to see the "infinite scroll" issue.

Comment: no probs bro i already worked out a solution to that problem and its working fine for me. still if u want to look around the site i'll give you a new pass.(its not completed yet). @MichaelFromin

Comment: Perhaps you could post what your solution was so that others can learn if they come across this post later?